# What's the proper way to (PEP8)line break for when constants are called from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8, code-structure

I'm using spyder and I have a code which goes something like this

```
    detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = gamma_detection(decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```

For which the second `i` in `decay_positions` exceeds the recommended amount of characters in a line(something like 90). I have the dynamical PEP8 analysis on so it naturally gives me warning for my code analysis. So what is the correct PEP8 way to do in this case? Is it

```
detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = \
gamma_detection(decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```

which technically still runs but it's giving me warning

`E122 continuation line missing indentation or outdented`

or is it

```
detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = gamma_detection(
    decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```

or is it

```
detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = gamma_detection(
                                        decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You offered options {1, 2, 3}.

Definitely use 2 or 3.
It's a matter of taste between them,
or what your favorite editor encourages you to use.
(Put it all on one line with cursor past the open paren, hit RETURN, and use the suggested indentation.)
As long as

```
$ flake8
```

does not complain, you're golden.
(Get it with `pip install flake8`.)

For lots of parameters,
or parameters that involve lengthy expressions,
you might even consider listing one param per line.

If you're assigning to lots of long identifiers,
you might consider surrounding the LHS in parens for the tuple unpack:

```
(detector_x, detector_y,
 smeared_x, smeared_y) = gamma_detection(
    decay_positions,
    cos_theta + epsilon * some_long_expression(),
    phi)
```

Comment: Is `flake8` just the standard protocol that's used in most compiler? So when I turn on "Real-time code style analysis" on Spyder is that basically using `flake8`?

Comment: Yup. Also, I sometimes tack on a line like `max-line-length = 90` to my `.flake8` config file, and I would expect anything linking against that library to respect such a config.

Answer (score 0):

Using autopep8 on VS code your code gets changed to the following:

```
detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = \
    gamma_detection(decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```

Now I took a look at the total length if this is a one-liner, which is 96 characters. Even though this exceeds the PEP8 limit of ~79 characters, I would still recommend to keep this as one line. In practice 79 characters is very short and readability doesn't decrease if you make lines of 100 characters. Where I work we also increased the guidelines for line length to 100 characters.

```
# 96 characters
detector_x, detector_y, smeared_x, smeared_y = gamma_detection(decay_positions, cos_theta, phi)
```